# How to match, lookup and project with filtering on the other table in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My goal is to get a list of active alerts and the corresponding read dates for a given user.

I have an `alerts` collection

```
{
    "id" : "id",
    "field1": 1,
    "field2": 1,
    "field3": 1,
    "field4": 1,
    "status" : { "name": "ACTIVE" }
}
```

I am tracking when a user has read an alert using a `alertstracking` collection

```
{ 
    "alertid" : "alertidvalue", 
    "userid" : "useridvalue", 
    "id" : "id", 
    "readdate" : ISODate("2020-02-14T00:45:45.959+0000")
}
```

This is the working query I have but was wondering if there are better/faster ways to do it.
I was going to index alertid, userid fields on the `alertstracking` collection.

```
db.getCollection("alerts").aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "status.name": "ACTIVE"
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "alertstracking",
            localField: "id",
            foreignField: "alertid",
            as: "alerttrack"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "id": 1,
            "field1": 1,
            "field2": 1,
            "field3": 1,
            "field4": 1,
            "useralerttrack": {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$alerttrack",
                    as: "track",
                    cond: {
                        $eq: ["$$track.userid", "useridvalue"]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "id": 1,
            "field1": 1,
            "field2": 1,
            "field3": 1,
            "field4": 1,
            "readdate": {
                $arrayElemAt: ["$useralerttrack.readdate", 0]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

I am hoping to avoid using `$project` twice and repeating the fields I want.
I had to do it to be able to access `useralerttrack`.

Comment: I don't see where `"$$track.userid"` is coming from.  This looks like a relational schema, why are you storing it in mongodb instead of a relational database?

Comment: @Joe It is coming from the `userid` field in the `alertstracking` collection.
I do come from a relational DB background and that's probably causing this. I will have to redesign this and still use MongoDB. Any pointers would be very helpful.. thanks

Comment: @pradhyo : Here `$eq: ["$$track.userid", "useridvalue"]` are you trying to pass an input & check against `alertstracking.userid` ?? So what is `useridvalue` ?

Comment: @whoami yes.. say users with ids "1", "2", "3" have all read alert "1", `alertstracking` will have three entries for alert "1" - one for each user.. I am trying to get the entries for only the user id I pass

Comment: @pradhyo : Let's after first `$project if you end up with two elements in `useralerttrack ` then `readdate` is that the latest that you want (from latest doc) ? Do you end up with two docs in `useralerttrack` ??

Comment: There can only be one entry for a alertid/userid combination.. since I just overwrite the readdate each time a user reads the alert.. `$arrayElemAt: ["$useralerttrack.readdate", 0]` was working as expected for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try that like this :

```
 db.getCollection("alerts").aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "status.name": "ACTIVE"
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup:
        {
            from: "alertstracking",
            let: { id: "$id" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match:
                    {
                        $expr:
                        {
                            $and:
                                [
                                    { $eq: ["$alertid", "$$id"] },
                                    { $eq: ["$userid", "useridvalue"] }
                                ]
                        }
                    }
                }, { $project: { _id: 0, readdate: 1 } }
            ],
            as: "readdate"
        }
    }, {
        $addFields: {
            readdate: {
                $arrayElemAt: ["$readdate.readdate", 0]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TSuAUTdnUsp)

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I wasn't clear. There are more fields on alerts that I don't want showing up in my result. That's why I was mentioning just the fields that I want in `project` each time.

The `project` part in your solution doesn't seem to do anything.. removing it produces the same result and I am not able to add/remove fields using that

Comment: @pradhyo : Fields with you’re mentioning & wanted to remove additional fields is from ‘alerts’ or ‘alertsTracking’ ? That $project will remove fields from ‘alertsTracking’ if you wanted to remove fields from ‘alerts’ then you need to replace outter stage of ‘addFields’ to ‘project’ and do what ever you wanted !!